# repo init LineageOS source error : Repo command failed: UpdateManifestError

Tags: android, git, terminal, repository, repo

I wonder if there is a problem in my repo env

when I try:

```
repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-20.0 --depth 1
```

I got the follow error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19WZ.png)

```
fatal: cannot obtain manifest https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git
================================================================================
Repo command failed: UpdateManifestError
```

I succeed in before, but it happen when i reinstall repo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j19WZ.png)

Comment: just `repo init` also has the same error

Comment: Try `repo --trace init <options>` to print more logs.

Comment: @ElpieKay here is new progess, I post a picture in question,thanks

Comment: Fetching the branch `lineage-20.0` failed, but it's right there and the repository is public. Try `git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git` and see if it prints the branch `lineage-20.0`. A workaround is to try another branch. If another branch can succeed, then download the `default.xml` of `lineage-20.0` from Github page and put it under `.repo/manifests/`, and then use `repo sync -m default.xml`.

Comment: `$ repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-20.0 --git-lfs
Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error [Errno 110] Connection timed out
fatal: double check your --repo-rev setting.
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'`

Comment: it doesn't work :( ,but 'refs/heads/lineage-20.0' is exist, I can not download any branch

Answer (score 0):

I think my git and repo environ is wrong, I delete .repo_.gitconfig.json, and reinstall git and repo, then it work